# Match a word, followed by two optionals group in any order

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a sort of parser for a little library.

My string is in the following format:

```
text = "Louis,Edward,John|85.56!26,Billy,Don!18|78.0,Dean"
```

Just to be more clear, this is a list of people **names**, separated by **commas** and followed by two optionals separator (**|** and **!**), after the first there is the **weight** that is a **number** with 0-2 decimals, while after the "!" there is an integer number that represents the age. Separators and related values could appear in any order, as you can see for *John* and for *Don*.

I need to extract with Regex (I know I could do it in many other ways) all the names with a length between 2 and 4 and the two separator and the following values, if they are present.

This is my **expected result**:

```
[('John', '|85.56', '!26'), ('Don', '|78.00' ,'!18'), ('Dean', '', '')]
```

I'm trying with this code:

```
import re
text = "Louis,Edward,John|85.56!26,Billy,Don!18|78.0,Dean"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w{2,4}\b)(\!\d+)?(\|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?')
search_result = pattern.findall(text)
print(search_result)
```

But this is the actual result:

```
[('John', '', '|85.56'), ('26', '', ''), ('Don', '!18', '|78.0'), ('Dean', '', '')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex seems to be giving what you want:

```
re.findall(r'(\b[a-z]{2,4}\b)(?:(!\d+)|(\|\d+(?:\.\d{,2})?))*', text, re.I)
#[('John', '!26', '|85.56'), ('Don', '!18', '|78.0'), ('Dean', '', '')]
```

If you do not want those names, you can easily filter them out.

Comment: I've Dill but not Billy, because of the length, it must be between 2 and 4.
So the right expression is: pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w{2,4}\b)(?:(!\d+)|(\|\d+\.\d{,2}))*')

Thank you, it works :)

Comment: As a side note, there is no point in `compile`ing a pattern unless you want to use it many times.

Comment: I found that your regex doesn't match the following string:
text = "Louis,Edward,John|85.56!26,Billy,Don|78,Dean"

The two separators are optionals and may appear in both orders. So, for an user I could have just the weight, for another just the age, for another both of them and for another one just the name.

Comment: Ok, is just missing one question mark just after 'd{,2})', because decimal digits are optionals. Now it seems perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Pyparsing is good at composing complex expressions from simpler ones, and includes many builtins for optional, unordered, and comma-delimited values. See the comments in the code below:

```
import pyparsing as pp

real = pp.pyparsing_common.real
integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer
name = pp.Word(pp.alphas, min=2, max=4)

# a valid person entry starts with a name followed by an optional !integer for age
# and an optional |real for weight; the '&' operator allows these to occur in either
# order, but at most only one of each will be allowed
expr = pp.Group(name("name") 
                + (pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('!') + integer("age"), default='')
                   & pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('|') + real("weight"), default='')))

# other entries that we don't care about
other = pp.Word(pp.alphas, min=5)

# an expression for the complete input line - delimitedList defaults to using
# commas as delimiters; and we don't really care about the other entries, just
# suppress them from the results; whitespace is also skipped implicitly, but that
# is not an issue in your given sample text
input_expr = pp.delimitedList(expr | pp.Suppress(other))

# try it against your test data
text = "Louis,Edward,John|85.56!26,Billy,Don!18|78.0,Dean"                        
input_expr.runTests(text)
```

Prints:

```
Louis,Edward,John|85.56!26,Billy,Don!18|78.0,Dean
[['John', 85.56, 26], ['Don', 18, 78.0], ['Dean', '', '']]
[0]:
  ['John', 85.56, 26]
  - age: 26
  - name: 'John'
  - weight: 85.56
[1]:
  ['Don', 18, 78.0]
  - age: 18
  - name: 'Don'
  - weight: 78.0
[2]:
  ['Dean', '', '']
  - name: 'Dean'
```

In this case, using the pre-defined real and integer expressions not only parses the values, but also does the conversion to int and float. The named parameters can be accessed like object attributes:

```
for person in input_expr.parseString(text):
    print("({!r}, {}, {})".format(person.name, person.age, person.weight))
```

Gives:

```
('John', 26, 85.56)
('Don', 18, 78.0)
('Dean', , )
```

Comment: When I try to execut your example: AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'pyparsing_common'

Comment: From the command line type `python -c "import pyparsing; print(pyparsing.__version__)"` to show what version of pyparsing you are running. `pyparsing_common` was introduced in version 2.1.4, the latest version is 2.3.1 (just released this past weekend). Use `pip install pyparsing -U` to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: Do you have a local file that you have named `pyparsing.py`? That would collide with the installed pyparsing module. `python -c "import pyparsing; print(pyparsing.__file__)"` will show you what file you are importing from.

Comment: Yes, the local file name was pyparsing.py. Thank you for your patience and congratulations for your library.